# Codeigniter custom url string

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and i am working on making a doctors site and need to allow users to search for doctors using simple url like http://www.mywebsite.com/newyork .so this url doesn't have any class as there can be many states and cant have class for each state. Should i change 404 override in routes script? Or there is a better way to achieve it

```
$route['(:any)']='search/check_state';
```

if i use above routing then other page like /login doesnt work.Please help

Comment: you should really spend more time reading the docs on how controllers work and error pages and routes

Comment: While I agree with the point above, It's also clear you need to understand how page requests work in general, I recommend some reading on the matter.

For example, The search you posted can easily be done with an index function in a class called 'newyork' without even touching  the routing, There's no need to maintain state here. the search will normally be conducted through GET or POST params that can even be posted to the same index function.

Comment: @Patrick : But if the search url includes any other state like california then according to you i should have another class 'california' in index page. I dont think thats a wise method if there are many states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make database that contains all states and do it this way

Inside search/check_state

```
// Get state from URL
$state = $this->uri->segment(1, "");

// Make sure state is not null and its found in database
if($state <> "" && $this->validateState($state)){
    // Valid state, continue
}else{
    // Give error message / redirect to 404 page
}
```

Add new function to controller

```
function validateState($state){
    // If database contains $state then return true else return false
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can also do it with POST form.

Make form into page where user gives input details

```
echo form_open(base_url().'path_to_post_validation');
// make form here that sends "state" into page that handles validation
echo form_close();
```

Handle POST validation

```
// Make sure user has send POST request
if($this->input->post()){

    // Set form validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('state', 'state', 'required|trim|xss_clean');

    // Run form validation
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){

        // Store state into variable
        $state = $this->input->post('state');

        // Check database that it contains $state and then continue or give error message
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i did it like this but ny question is basically to know if there is any alternate way rather than using a wildcard entry in routers page

Comment: One way is to send state with GET or POST, then you dont need routes.

Comment: if i use get or post then the url cant be a simple one like website.com/newyork ...is it right?

Comment: Well, basicly it can, but it would be pointless. Url would look something like website.com/search

Answer (score 0):

got it try

```
$route['search/check_state/:any'] ='search/check_state';
```

Comment: but the url will be of the form http://www.mywebsite.com/[state name]. so not sure how the above route will work here